# how to understand the convolutional layer output depth

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am a bit confused about the output depth of the convolutional layer. For example, as shown in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MT5V4.png) image, there are `2` filters of size `3 x 3` for input image of size `6 x 6 x 3`, the output is a `4 x 4 x 2` tensor. How does the three color channels fuse into `1` layer? but in some network after the convolution layer, the color channel is still the same, for example here `model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=5, strides=1, activation=None, input_shape=(128,128,3)))` (TensorFlow), the output shape of this layer is `(5, 5, 3, 32)`, where I didn't specify any code to say keep color channel or not.

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=5,strides=1, activation=None, input_shape=(128,128,3)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(2,2))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(units=1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))


for layer in model.layers:
    # check for convolutional layer
    if 'conv' not in layer.name:
        continue
    # get filter weights
    filters, biases = layer.get_weights()
    print(layer.name, filters.shape)
```

so when I print the conv output layer shape it shows as conv2d_46 (5, 5, 3, 32). when I print the summary the out shape show different, what is None? Layer (type) Output Shape Param #

```
conv2d_45 (Conv2D) (None, 124, 124, 32) 2432
batch_normalization_38 (Bat (None, 124, 124, 32) 128
chNormalization)
activation_36 (Activation) (None, 124, 124, 32) 0
max_pooling2d_17 (MaxPoolin (None, 62, 62, 32) 0
g2D)
dropout_26 (Dropout) (None, 62, 62, 32) 0
flatten_11 (Flatten) (None, 123008) 0
dense_23 (Dense) (None, 64) 7872576
dropout_27 (Dropout) (None, 64) 0
dense_24 (Dense) (None, 1) 65
activation_37 (Activation) (None, 1) 0
```

Answer (score 2):

In the example image posted by OP for input of size `6 x 6 x 3` (`input_dim=6, channel_in=3`) with `2` filters of size `3 x 3` (`filter_size=3`) the spatial dimension can be computed as `(input_dim - filter_size + 2 * padding) / stride + 1` = `(6 - 3 + 2 * 0)/1 + 1 = 4` (where `padding=0` and `stride=1`)

[image]

Thus the `4 x 4` feature map. The operation used in standard CNN layer for computing the element in this feature map is that of fully-connected layer. Consider an example filter and image patch below (from [CS231n](https://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/)):

[image]

then the output element is computed as:

```py
import numpy as np

# filter weights of size 3 x 3 x 3
w0 = np.array([
    [[0., -1., 0.],
     [1., -1., 0.],
     [0., -1., 0.]],
    [[0., 1., -1.],
     [-1., 1., 0.],
     [1., -1., 0.]],
    [[-1., 0., 0.],
     [0., -1., -1.],
     [1., -1., 0.]]
])
# bias value for the filter
b0 = 1

# an input image patch 3 x 3 x 3
x_patch = np.array([
    [[0., 0., 0.],
     [0., 2., 1.],
     [0., 1., 1.]],
    [[0., 0., 0.],
     [0., 0., 1.],
     [0., 0., 1.]],
    [[0., 0., 0.],
     [0., 0., 0.],
     [0., 0., 2.]]
])

# define the operation for each channel
>>> op = lambda xs, ws: np.sum(xs*ws)
>>> op(x_patch[:, :, 0], w0[:, :, 0]) # channel 1
0.0
>>> op(x_patch[:, :, 1], w0[:, :, 1]) # channel 2
-3.0
>>> op(x_patch[:, :, 2], w0[:, :, 2]) # channel 3
0.0

# add the values for each channel (this is where 
# channel dimension is summed over) plus the bias
>>> 0.0 + (-3.0) + 0.0 + b0
-2.0

# or simply
>>> np.sum(x_patch * w0) + b0
-2.0
```

This is generally the case for CNN, which can alterantively be visualized as

[image]

compared to [Depth-wise convolution](https://medium.com/@zurister/depth-wise-convolution-and-depth-wise-separable-convolution-37346565d4ec) where the channel dimension is kept as is:

[image]

TensorFlow provides separate implementations for each in `tf.keras.layers.Conv2D` ([here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.9/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv2D)) and `tf.keras.layers.DepthwiseConv2D` ([here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.9/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/DepthwiseConv2D)) so you can use according to your application.

I cannot reproduce the output dimension of `5 x 5 x 3 x 32` for your second example (using tf v2.9.0):

```py
import tensorflow as tf

# The inputs are 128 x 128 RGB images with 
# `data_format=channels_last` (by default) and 
# the batch size is 4.
>>> input_shape = (4, 128, 128, 3)
>>> x = tf.random.normal(input_shape)
>>> y = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(
 32, 
 kernel_size=5, 
 strides=1, 
 activation=None, 
 input_shape=(128, 128, 3)
)(x)
>>> print(y.shape)
(4, 124, 124, 32)
```

The example code is slightly adjusted from the official documentation [example](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.9/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv2D#examples).

Comment: cool, maybe the version is different,thanks

Comment: Can you add a [minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code for your example in the question?

Comment: many thanks for your patience, I just put the code under. by the way, maybe stupid questions, I am also wondering for one layer there can be many neurons, how to avoid two neurons learn the same pattern?

Comment: Since weights represent neurons, the reason for the same patterns could be similar updates due to improper initialization. It might be a good idea to look at the initializer used (for smaller networks, Gaussian initialization works well, but you can also try Xavier initialization) and consider batch normalization and dropout.

Comment: [Here](https://medium.com/machine-learning-world/how-to-debug-neural-networks-manual-dc2a200f10f2) is a list of commonly used NN debugging methods. Also check Full Stack DL course [lecture](https://fullstackdeeplearning.com/spring2021/lecture-7/), [Chapter 5](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap5.html) of NN&DL book, Defining and Intialization [section](https://github.com/fastai/fastbook/blob/master/17_foundations.ipynb), and [this](https://pouannes.github.io/blog/initialization/) blogpost for theoretical discussion.